# Postgres configuration

Tags: user-accounts, freebsd, postgresql

I'm installing PosgreSQL 9.0 over FreeBSD 8.1. In MySQL I have to change the root SQL user's password, here how can I do? And how can I add other SQL users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the 'postgres' password with something like :

psql --echo-all --echo-queries postgres -U postgres --command "alter role postgres encrypted password 'YOURPASSWORD'"

Answer (score 2):

Create users with the `createuser` shell command.

Answer (score 1):

to make sure, that there is no password in .bash_history or .psql_history i use the psql-comannd "\password":

```
$ sudo -u postgres -i
$ psql
# \password
Enter new password: 
Enter it again: 
# create user <user_name>;
# \password <user_name>
```